Вычислить сумму ячеек
В таблице 1 Выбираем данные и Параметры.

В таблице 2 находится сводная таблица. Подскажите, как вычислить сумму пересечения выбранных Данных и Параметров? (прим. Выбрали Параметр 3 и Данные 3, 4, 5 = Сумма ячеек). Google sheets


Api? Не формулой вычислить?

Пример, мы выбрали на листе 2 - флажки, параметр 1, 3 и данные 1, 2, 3, 5, необходимо вычислить сумму пересечения ячеек по выбранному столбцу Параметр 1/данные 1 + параметр 1/ данные 2 и т.д и так же по Параметру 3. Необходимо сделать одной формулой.

Так почему тогда у вопроса метка про апи?

Покажите ссылку на живую таблицу. Если выбирать только один параметр, то сравнительно просто (при этом для выбора параметра достаточно выпадающего списка, не нужны флажки).

Да, с одним параметром все понятно, а вот с несколькими, задачка усложняется

Необходимо сделать именно с флажками, табличкой в течении сегодняшнего дня поделюсь

Открыл доступ по почте в профиле

"Мелкие" формулы видны на картинке.
Формула суммы в каждой строке:
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2=False;0;SUM(SUMIF('Лист1'!$B$1:$G$1;$F$2:$F$11;INDEX('Лист1'!$B$2:$G$11;MATCH(A2;'Лист1'!$A$2:$A$11;0))))))


